# JMeter Cookie Manager edits response

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I have a pretty weird JMeter operation. Cookie Manager overwrites the response from the request from which I would expect the cookie value. If I disable the Cookie Manager, the value of the cookie will normally appear in the response.
After the request i'm using a Regular Expression Extractor to get the value of the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie Manager itself doesn't "edit" response, it just reads the cookies from [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header, stores them internally and on subsequent requests if current domain and path matches sends cookie(s) in [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header

So the fact that you're not receiving the cookie might mean that the cookie is already present/sent to the server.

You can [enable debug logging](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for the HTTP cookie manager by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

and then you will be able to see what exactly happens to cookies in jmeter.log file.

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)